# Using jQuery or JavaScript to Add Attribute to Anchors After DOM Already Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application that requires the "ontouchstart" attribute to be added to each and every anchor in order to have the anchor:active CSS state to work on iOS devices.

Trouble is that the entire application loads content via AJAX after the DOM has already loaded, which means any `$(selector).attr('ontouchstart','')` call will only work on the initial screen, not content added later via AJAX.

Because each screen is being loaded by separate functions (in some cases being constructed by the function itself) I would like to find a solution that allows a single jQuery or JavaScript call that applies to all anchors, even those added after the DOM is loaded rather than going through each and every function and adding in the call individually (there are hundreds of them).

Is this even possible? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the DOMNodeInserted event:

```
$(document).bind('DOMNodeInserted', function(event) {
  if (event.target.nodeName == 'A') {
    $(event.target).attr('ontouchstart','');
  }
});
```

The event itself will fire when any type of node is added to the DOM, the code just tests the node name (tag) and adds the attribute.

Comment: Very interesting! Is there any performance concerns to firing the event on each node insertion?

Comment: I've read that JS mutation events (of which this is one) do have performance penalties, indeed Mozilla roundly [discourage their use](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Performance_best_practices_in_extensions#section_8), they're [deprecated in DOM Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMNodeInserted)...but you *might* get away with using it depending on how complex your application is. Best thing to do would be to run a benchmark with and without if you can :-). I just wanted to present it as a possible alternative

Comment: Thank you; this is definitely the best option... I'll just have to see about the performance penalties =)

Answer (score 2):

Try using the [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) or [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) event listeners.  These both work with DOM elements added after the onload event.

Comment: I've used $.live() in the past, however it is my understanding that it is event specific. What event would I use in my case outlined above?

Comment: Reading again it sounds like you're not waiting for any event (or rather the AJAX call is the event).  As far as I know you can't set an attribute on "future" elements.  You would have to add that attribute after every ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) events are what you're looking for.